# XCode Preview with Color Loop for SwiftUI Previews not working anymore

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview, xcode14

Before XCode 14, the following syntax was working well to loop through the different color schemes.

```swift
static var previews: some View {
    
    ForEach(ColorScheme.allCases, id: \.self) {
        MyView()
            .preferredColorScheme($0)
    }
}
```

Starting XCode 14, this results in

`PreviewUpdateTimedOutError: Updating took more than 5 seconds`

I suspect, this has to do with the new button in XCode to display the Color Scheme Variants in Preview now, but i rather like the old behaviour back.

[image]

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Xcode bug Apple is aware of: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711723
As a workaround, you can use preview variants support as suggested there.

If you just want to see the dark mode case (or something similar to it), this is what I've been doing:

```
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        .background(Color.black)
```

***This is not exactly the same*** than `preferredColorScheme(.dark)` but it works good enough to have something in the preview while Apple fixes it.